# Is there anyway to install react-scripts as global

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

**'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

*can i use this command in npm ? ***

> npm install -g react-scripts@latest

Comment: npm install react-scripts -g , it will work

Comment: Saddam Mohsen. Please accept my answer (green checkmark on the side), if you find that it satisfactorily answers your question. This allows other visitors to find the best solution, as well as rewards me for helping solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

### You can, but you probably shouldn't.

`react-scripts` comes from the Create React App developers. In their official [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) they write:

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
> install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package
> using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove
> create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Make certain your terminal is located in the root of your project directory, in the same level as your `package.json` and not in some other directory.

### It's Still Not Working

If you're still having trouble, it's likely your `node_modules` are having some issues. I'd recommend deleting the `node_modules` folder, and running `npm install` to regenerate them. This fixed my similar issue last night.